# Copy macro in a template file with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

My problem:

I have two workbooks.

Workbook1: constructed from a template file with macro

Workbook2: empty

In a loop I export my datastructures. In each loop passing I copy the template to wokrbook2 and then write the data in it, mark the row where I was for the next loop passing, and then do the same again.

At the end I have copied the template multiple times ( as many times as I have datasets) to the workbook2 and written data in the according template.

My problem: There is a macro in the original template file which is gone when I open my newly created file. All the data is correctly written, just the macro functionality is missing.

Comment: Why don't you open a copy of Workbook 1, replace the template values with the real values, and save that?

Comment: Problem solved, maybe unlogical but it works.

I first copy the template to the new workbook and then iterate through all rows and throw them away. Result is an empty sheet, but the macro is still there.

Then I succesively copy the template rows from the template workbook and fill these each time with data. (in a loop)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know other solutions but there is one limitation of Apache POI is : 
`Macros can not be created.  However, reading and re-writing files containing macros will safely preserve the macros.`

Check [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html)

Comment: post it as answer, whatever u have done. it would be helpful to others

Comment: I posted it as comment to my original question above.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, maybe unlogical but it works.

I first copy the template to the new workbook and then iterate through all rows and throw them away. Result is an empty sheet, but the macro is still there.

Then I copy the template rows from the template workbook and fill these each time with data